# SLAM - detect initial position

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, position, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,
I just performed SLAM with navigation_stack and V-REP simulator. As I know for know, we should give initial position of the robot so that AMCL performs localization and costmaps are generated properly.

My question is: Is there a way to skip the procedure of *the user* giving the initial position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232608/slam---detect-initial-position/) by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-22**:
You can set the initial pose estimate in your AMCL launch file. It's still the "user" that provides it, but at least you don't have to do it in RViz. What I usually do is set the initial pose to `[0 0 0]` and then start the robot roughly at the origin of the SLAM-generated map. It quickly converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

you could try the global_localization service of amcl, this spreads the particles all over the map. Then you have to drive around and maybe you get the correct position after the particles converged.

---

Originally posted by [fsteinhardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/4889/fsteinhardt/) with karma: 306 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2016-04-22**:
Hi.. I used global_localization but I think it needs a lot driving over the map to work. It would be nicer if it needed only a 360 degrees relative to its own frame (for example)..

**Comment by [MariaKrgr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26662/mariakrgr/) on 2016-04-22**:
In addition, in my simulation this initial localization is happening by driving into the 'room' *without* calling /global_localization service...  It seems like this service is needless or there is something I am doing wrong..

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2016-04-22**:
I suggest you visualize the filter particles in rviz and compare their distribution when you initialize the node against using the /global_localization service.